# How to get left mouse click event in Tree View

Tags: qt, qt5

I have implemented a QTreeview with QAbstractItemModel how can i be notified if i click on the tree view item with left mouse click.Do we have any function like  OnLButtonDown() avalible for the tree view.

```
WavefrontRenderer::WavefrontRenderer(TreeModel* model , QWidget *parent) : 
QMainWindow(parent)
 {
    setupUi(this);  
    treeView->setModel(model);
    treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
    treeView->setAcceptDrops(true);
    treeView->installEventFilter(this);   
    connect(pushButtonAddGroup, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(insertRow()));
     connect(pushButtonAddChild , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, 
    SLOT(insertChild()));
    connect(pushButtonDeleteGroup , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, 
    SLOT(removeRow()));
    connect( ButtonSphere, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(AddSphere()));
    connect(treeView , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(message()));   
 }
```

I tried to connect the treeview to clicked slot but this did not work for me.

Since i am new to qt i am not sure if we connect the treeview same way as we connect buttons to the clicked slots.

Comment: You have the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) sginal.

Comment: How can i connect it to treeview ?

Comment: i tried connect(treeView , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(message()));

Comment: did not work for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you've tried so far and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi GM i have updated the code.

Comment: i want to call a function when we click on a treeitem.

Comment: You don't seem to initialize `treeView` anywhere.

Comment: I am but in my main function from there i am passing model as a pointer.

Comment: TreeModel* model = new TreeModel("RootElement", &cont);
 WavefrontRenderer w( model );

Comment: That is the model, but where does `treeView` get its value?

Comment: @thuga: `treeView` is an inherited member and it is initialized in `setupUi()` which is a function in the base class (`Ui_WavefrontRenderer` or similar) which is not shown here because the header code is missing.

Comment: @MartinHennings I see. Usually that is done with an `ui` variable.

Comment: @thuga That's a matter of flavor. Some use `ui.` member, some `ui->` pointer, and some use inheritance. I've seen them all, even within the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check your connections:

```
bool ok = connect(...);
Q_ASSERT(ok);
```

If you do that, you'll find that connecting to the `clicked()` signal doesn't work.

If you then take a look at your error console you'll see a Qt message that the signal `clicked()` is not found in `QTreeView`.
That's because the **parameters** need to be included in the `SIGNAL(...)` macro.

Either put them there **but just the type without the parameter name**:

```
bool ok = connect(treeView, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(message()));
```

or avoid this pitfall by using the [new connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax):

```
bool ok = connect(treeView, &QAbstractItemView::clicked, this, &WavefrontRenderer::message);
```

This will give you a compiler error if the signal or slot doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot martin it works with the new syntax , i have one question why it did not work with the old syntax.

Comment: Even the other buttons are working with the old syntax.

Comment: Compare the function signatures: `void QAbstractItemView::doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)` has `QModelIndex const &` which is **mandatory**, but `void QAbstractButton::clicked(bool checked = false)` has `bool` which has a **default value**.